# Trouble with scanner and delimiter

Tags: arrays, string, file, delimiter

im having trouble with my scanner reading my text file with delemiter. Im trying to save each string in an array but when i print it the array stays emty... Idk why

```
        Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
        s.useDelimiter("@");


         int length = (upperBound - lowerBound)+1;
         String [] Entries = new String[length];

         for(int i=0; i < length; i++)
         {
             Entries[i] = s.next();
         }

     //When I print this the array location is empty:(           
     System.out.println(Entries[0]);
```

this is the content of my text file:

```
  The Germans occupy the rump Czech lands@Germany invades Denmark and Norway@Nazi Germany and its Axis partners invade the Soviet Union@
```

Comment: hi! I can't help you because I don't know which programming language this is. Add a language tag!

Comment: I think upperBound - lowerBound must be non-positive

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop to read the file and store items to the array like this:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    int length = (upperBound - lowerBound)+1;
    String [] Entries = new String[length];
    int count = 0;
    while (s.hasNext()){
        s.useDelimiter("@");
        Entries[count] = s.next();
        count++;
    }
```

Use a for loop to print out your array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Entries.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Entries[i]);
    }
```

I would also suggest using "entries" as a variable name. It's good practice to keep variable names in [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)